# Delete read-only files in azure blob store owned by dropped user

Tags: azure-blob-storage

How would one delete files in a blob store folder if the group and other permissions don't allow it but the owner userID is no longer valid?  We use Hadoop commands on Linux to put data into the blob store.

```
Found 501 items
-rw-r-----   1 fmruser supergroup          0 2016-09-23 21:28 wasbs://somefolder@someblobstore.blob.core.windows.net/somedirectory/_SUCCESS
-rw-r-----   1 fmruser supergroup  290348992 2016-09-23 21:18 wasbs://somefolder@someblobstore.blob.core.windows.net/somedirectory/part-m-00000
-rw-r-----   1 fmruser supergroup  330735095 2016-09-23 21:18 wasbs://somefolder@someblobstore.blob.core.windows.net/somedirectory/part-m-00001
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure portal provides the subscription admin the functionality.